# Add meta tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

How to add a meta tag just after title tag in a HTML page by using Beautiful Soup(library). I am using python language for coding and unable to do this.

Answer (score 13):

Use `soup.create_tag()` to create a new `<meta>` tag, set attributes on that and add it to your document `<head>`.

```
metatag = soup.new_tag('meta')
metatag.attrs['http-equiv'] = 'Content-Type'
metatag.attrs['content'] = 'text/html'
soup.head.append(metatag)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <html><head><title>Hello World!</title>
... </head><body>Foo bar</body></html>
... ''')
>>> metatag = soup.new_tag('meta')
>>> metatag.attrs['http-equiv'] = 'Content-Type'
>>> metatag.attrs['content'] = 'text/html'
>>> soup.head.append(metatag)
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Hello World!
  </title>
  <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  Foo bar
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya its fine working correctly for normal keywords. But some contents are not possible to add in meta tag. It generates a encoding error. I have tried .encode('UTC-8') to solve problem but unable to resolve it.

Comment: Use Unicode strings when inserting new data; any *encode* errors then are due to I/O errors (printing Unicode to a terminal that cannot handle it or a file that cannot handle it, etc.).

Comment: could u please give me any example?

Comment: I already gave an example in my post on how to add meta tags. It works just fine with Unicode strings. There are many ways you can trigger a Unicode encoding or decoding exception in Python, an example of mine will not show you how to avoid the one *you* are seeing in your code. Perhaps you need to post a new question with that specific problem; make sure to include a reproducible code example with such a question.